# probability of chosen $4$ numbers

Tags: probability

> $4$ numbers are chosen from $1$ to $20$. Then find probability that no two choosen number are consecutive, is

My Try: Total ways is $\displaystyle \binom{20}{4}$

and favorable ways

$$x_{1}\cdots  A\cdots  x_{2} \cdots B\cdots x_{3}\cdots C\cdots x_{4}\cdots D\cdots x_{5}$$

$$x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}=16$$

and $x_{1},x_{5}\geq 0$ and $x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}\geq 1\;,x_{i}\in \{0,1,2,\cdots ,16\}$

$$x_{1}+x'_{2}+x'_{3}+x'_{4}+x_{5}=20$$

Total no. of non negative integer solution  is

$\displaystyle \binom{20+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{24}{4}$

My question is can we solve it without using above method

please explain me in detail Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your method is completely correct, you can solve it this way. I think the solution of your equation seems to be wrong. As you have said.:$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=16$ where $x_1,x_5 \ge 0$ and $x_2,x_3,x_4\ge 1 $, the number of ways should be $C^{17}_4$.
Your equation changes to:
$x_1+(x^`_2+1)+(x^`_3+1)+(x^`_4+1)+x_5=16$
where each variable now assumes a value greater than equal to 0